# Is 'width' applicable to a textarea?

Tags: html, css, textarea, width

Is the CSS `'width'` property applicable to a `<textarea>`?

In practice, [people say that they use it successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271067), for example using a rule like this:

```
textarea
{
    width:100%;
}
```

What's confusing me is that the [CSS 2.1 specification for width](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-width-property) says,

> This property specifies the content
>   width of boxes generated by
>   block-level and replaced elements. 
>   This property does not apply to
>   non-replaced inline-level elements.

I thought that a textarea is an inline-level element, because e.g. markup like this ...

```
<p>
This is some more text:
<textarea name="mytextarea" rows="3" cols="15">Text in the text area</textarea>
And even more, more text.
</p>
```

... creates a single paragraph block with text to the left and right of the `<textarea>`, and that therefore according to the spec the width shouldn't be applicable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Textarea is an inline level element… a **replaced** inline element (you get a form control, not the simple content of the element).

The spec excludes non-replaced inline elements, but textarea is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Width is not an acceptable attribute of the textarea element. The size of a textarea can be specified by the cols and rows attributes, although it can be better controlled through the CSS height and width properties.

Answer (score -1):

you should use the 'cols' property to set the width of the textarea.

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_textarea.asp

Comment: No. You should specify the number of cols, but if you really want to set the width than CSS is much more flexible. (And avoid W3Schools, it is error prone).