# The 100% width HTML element problem

Tags: html, css, dom

When assigning some HTML elements (like a form input) 100% width - you can no longer apply any additional styles that might effect the width. Things like `border` or `padding` will cause the element to exceed 100%. This results in awkward elements that may be outside of their parent elements.

Since CSS doesn't support `width: 100% - 2px;` The only way I know around this is to use an absolute pixel width (`width: 98px`) or chop the element off at 100% which is not really an option.

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
<input style="width:100%; border: 1px solid #000;" />
</div>
```

Are they're any other ways around this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Along with [adding another div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271067/how-can-i-make-a-textarea-100-width-without-overflowing-when-padding-is-present/272632#272632), the solution will soon be to use CSS 3 to add the [box-sizing attribute](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) to the CSS rules. This new [CSS 3](http://jhop.me/css/css3/the-css3-box-sizing-concept-a-solution-to-a-longstanding-problem) value already works in IE 8 and all other browsers - so if you don't mind skipping IE 6 & 7 you can use it now!

```
textarea {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
        box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Comment: It's funny that all of us copy-paste this css snippet from the same site every time we need it :P

Answer (score 4):

You can make a container that's 100% without chrome (borders, padding), and then place a block element within, with whatever chrome you want - a block element will fill-up the total width by default.

```
<style>
.container {width:100%;border:0:margin:0;}
.thingy {border:1px solid black;margin:2px;background:#ddd;}
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="thingy">
    Both worlds?
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems this only works on div elements. However, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271067/how-can-i-make-a-textarea-100-width-without-overflowing-when-padding-is-present/272632#272632 shows a way of adding another div around the element and applying the styling to it.

Comment: Well, the internal element has to be a block level element (not `inline`, or `inline-block`).

Comment: +1 what I would have said if I was quick enough. :) May also be worth noting that CSS3 gives us `box-sizing: content-box`, which subtracts borders and padding from the calculated width.

Comment: Ooo, a preview of the future... hooray for the death of the `add extra divs` solution :)  Thanks @RP

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but it's worth mentioning that since CSS3, you can use [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```
width: calc(100% - 2px);
```