# Textarea resize window

Tags: html, css

Go to http://kennethhedegaard.com/html2/index.html

Try to resize the window.

Can't figure out why the textarea is not scaling...

Kenneth

Comment: Try not to add padding on elements with 100% width unless you are intending for them to reach outside of their parent. I assume that is why you added the `max-width` to the textarea.

Comment: if you mean that right border of the textarea is not showing, it's because you set its width to 100% but, adding padding you are going over 100%. And parent div hides left border because of "overflow: hidden"

Comment: Here are some tips to help you get better answers. Please don't make us go over to your website and look at what's over there. It's better if we have all the necessary information right here in the question text. Pictures of the exact area in your website that you're referring to are helpful, as well as code snippets that you think may be causing the problem. If you wanna go the extra mile and make it a super helpful question, you can reproduce the problem in a front-end sandbox such as http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://codepen.io/ to let us see exactly what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271067/how-can-i-make-a-textarea-100-width-without-overflowing-when-padding-is-present) to make your textarea filling properly its parent.

In the code you posted the textarea has 100% width and padding which, with default values, means that you are going over with the padding. Moreover the div which contains the textarea has overflow set to hidden and that's why you cant se right border

EDIT (in case link suddently dies):

You have to add this class or rules to your textarea:

```
.boxsizingBorder {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Cheers

Comment: what's the right way you want to resize it? And which browser are you using?