# White space at bottom of simple html after <textarea>

Tags: html, css

I have simple web-page. I need my textarea to take 100% width and height of page. And for that I did this:

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
textarea {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  resize: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page2.css">
 <title>Page 2</title>
</head>
<body>
 <textarea wrap></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

As far as I know, I have no margin collapse. I searched a lot, but can't understand what is causing this white space at the bottom.

p.s. red border is added for the sake of debugging.

Thanks

Comment: The duplicate is about an image, but the problem and solution is the same if you replace the image with a textarea.

Comment: Did you try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271067/how-can-i-make-a-textarea-100-width-without-overflowing-when-padding-is-present?

Comment: @Quentin I am sorry, hadn't searched for img same problem. That totally solved my question!

Answer (score -2):

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0px;
  padding:0px;
}
textarea {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  resize: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  text-align: justify;
}  
</style>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page2.css">
  <title>Page 2</title>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea wrap></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```