# Textarea doesn't stretch when parent has max-height and overflow scroll

Tags: html, css, textarea, overflow

I want the textarea to be stretchable in height. But the fixed `(max-)height` prevents this.
I thought the `overflow-y: scroll;` would fix this, but as you can see in the snippet, it doesn't.

Why doesn't the textarea stretches and why won't the button go down behind the border?

```css
div {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 width: 400px;
 max-height: 70px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <button>Save</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because of the `display: flex`. you can simply wrap the text area inside an element:

```css
.a {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 width: 400px;
 max-height: 70px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 border: 1px solid red;
}


textarea{
  width:100%;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* for 100% width https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271067/how-can-i-make-a-textarea-100-width-without-overflowing-when-padding-is-present */
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class><textarea></textarea></div>
  <button>Save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @JelmerOvereem  I edited the answer for 100% width https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271067/how-can-i-make-a-textarea-100-width-without-overflowing-when-padding-is-present