# Border of text input element goes beyond containing table

Tags: html

With the following HTML, the input element's width goes beyond the edge of the table's border.  What is the proper way to have the input element take up the entire cell content's but still have the same margin on the right edge as it shows on the left?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<table style="border: 1px solid #000000;" width="100%">
<tr>
<td><input style="width:100%"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Huh? It shouldn't do that. Can you show an example (ideally a http://jsfiddle.net)? In what browsers does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that input widths are evaluated without taking into account the default border (and maybe padding, IIRC) of the input itself.  Try setting `padding: 0px; border: 0px` and check it.

Also, see 
[Problem with <input type='text' /> and <textarea> width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259455/problem-with-input-type-text-and-textarea-width)
or [How can I make a TextArea 100% width without overflowing when padding is present in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271067/how-can-i-make-a-textarea-100-width-without-overflowing-when-padding-is-present) for a solution - this has come up before.